# Processing times for homemade pectin

Tags: food-safety, canning, recipe-scaling

Does anybody know water bath canning processing times for homemade pectin?  I would like to can homemade apple pectin in 1 litre jars.  I used underripe apples

Comment: [This article](https://www.thespruceeats.com/homemade-apple-pectin-1327832) suggests boiling for at least 10 minutes depending on altitude.